# Formatting text in a list in app inventor 2

Tags: listpicker, app-inventor

I have a list that I want to display some text as bold and other parts not bold. First of all I have been accomplishing this when not inside of a list by just making a bunch of labels and then manually going through the text adding `\n` and spaces for formatting, which takes forever. If there is an easier way of doing that I would love to know. Anyway my question is how can I add formatted text to a list.

[image]

So instead of those individual text elements I want to add multiple formatted text elements in place of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I add formatted text to a list

sorry, that's unfortunately not possible with App Inventor

you can take a look at [this App Inventor Classic example](http://puravidaapps.com/label.php), which uses some HTML to do the formatting

Comment: yes, but you have to convert it manually, because there is still no conversion tool available...